# Read each name from each line in file 1, look for same name in file 2, compare values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have two .txt files:

file1.txt contains:

```
model1 2.37
model2 3.33
model3 4.25
```

file2.txt contains:

```
model2 2.65
model1 2.39
model3 2.34
```

How could I read each line of file1.txt and for each line:

1. List item
2. read the model
3. search for it in file2.txt
4. compare the two values, i.e. model1 has increased by 0.02, model3 has decreased by -1.91.
5. report back the difference to another .txt file

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service, this question is far too broad. I'd recommend starting with a structured tutorial, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: I think this question asks too much. Split it into smaller questions and offer examples of what you have tried, and why it is not working. This isn't a site where we code stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write your whole program for you, but here are some pointers:

```
vals1 = open('file1.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
vals2 = open('file2.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
vals1 = dict([item.split() for item in vals1])
vals2 = dict([item.split() for item in vals2])
```

Use the above code to unpack the values into a dictionary.

Next, iterate over `vals1`, and for each key, look for the key in `vals2`, and add `vals2[key]-vals1[key]` to a 3<sup>rd</sup> dictionary (after converting them from strings to floats). Then, simply write to a new file.